# How can I move the first 2 pdf files in each folder in a directory (and each subdirectory) to a single folder using a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I have a directory that contains several hundred folders, many of which contain other folders, inside of which are anywhere from 6 or 7 to several hundred files of assorted types. I need a batch file that can copy the first 2 PDF files in each folder, including sub-folders, and add them to one, separate folder.

I don't think it should make a difference, but not every folder contains 2 or more PDF files. Many contain only other folders, in which case those folders should be searched. Others contain just 1 PDF, in which case it should be added to the separate folder with the others.

I have never written/used a batch file and any guidance, explanations or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A good starting point is writing some code. A bad start on StackOverflow is to ask for code for free. Hence please try something on your own, and if you are stuck at a certain point, come back here, describe precisely what you want your code to do and what it actually does. Consult also these help topics: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: if you would really think of a good question you could easy google answer;   you have few problems: 1) finding files  recursive (with specific params) 2) copy files; so try always to understand what really you want computer to do then it will be easy to find answers. and try to some work on your own always first.